# How to return images in flask response?

Tags: python, flask

As an example, this URL:

```
http://example.com/get_image?type=1
```

should return a response with a `image/gif` MIME type. I have two static `.gif` images,
and if type is 1, it should return `ok.gif`, else return `error.gif`. How to do that in flask?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

You use something like

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    if request.args.get('type') == '1':
       filename = 'ok.gif'
    else:
       filename = 'error.gif'
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/gif')
```

to send back `ok.gif` or `error.gif`, depending on the type query parameter. See the documentation for the [`send_file` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_file) and the [`request` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data) for more information.

Comment: any idea how to do that with flask-restful ?

Comment: @DavidV. I am trying the same thing. I am going to use an alternate for now. Save the response as a png file and somehow create a URL for that . Then embed that URL in my html page.

Comment: how do i send multiple gifs as return here?

Comment: It is worth nothing that `send_file` is an insecure method of sending files, which does not do any sanity checks and is not recommended if sanity checks are handled in your code. More information can be found on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252955/flask-when-to-use-send-file-send-from-directory)

Comment: what is the path of an image should i write? should i specify the path from the root directory: ```filename = './flaskapp/assets/imgs/ok.gif'``` ?

Comment: @AlexNikonov just pass the endpoint that calls returns the actual path of the file. So, for `@app.route('/vid/<filename>')` which returns `send_file('path_of_video')`, pass `<video src='/vid/output.mp4'>`