# Flask to return image stored in database

Tags: python, binary, flask

My images are stored in a MongoDB, and I'd like to return them to the client,  here is how the code is like:

```
@app.route("/images/<int:pid>.jpg")
def getImage(pid):
    # get image binary from MongoDB, which is bson.Binary type
    return image_binary
```

However, it seems that I can't return binary directly in Flask? My idea so far:

1. Return the `base64` of the image binary. The problem is that IE<8 doesn't support this.
2. Create a temporary file then return it with `send_file`.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return images in flask response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637153/how-to-return-images-in-flask-response)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Create a response object with the data and then set the content type header. Set the content disposition header to `attachment` if you want the browser to save the file instead of displaying it.

```
@app.route('/images/<int:pid>.jpg')
def get_image(pid):
    image_binary = read_image(pid)
    response = make_response(image_binary)
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
    response.headers.set(
        'Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='%s.jpg' % pid)
    return response
```

Relevant: [werkzeug.Headers](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/#werkzeug.Headers) and [flask.Response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects)

You can pass a file-like object and the header arguments to `send_file` to let it set up the complete response. Use `io.BytesIO` for binary data:

```
return send_file(
    io.BytesIO(image_binary),
    mimetype='image/jpeg',
    as_attachment=True,
    download_name='%s.jpg' % pid)
```

Prior to Flask 2.0, `download_name` was called `attachment_filename`.

Comment: Does send_file close the file object after sending? If it is not a BytesIO, but some other file-object that does require a call to close(), who will call it?

Comment: Using Python 3 and Flask 0.12, providing a binary string (`b'<binary image data>'`) may result in a `UnicodeError`. `send_file()` may be just better.

Comment: @Baruch  use `with` clause?

Comment: despite of the question about image, here is ```content-type``` for any file type ```application/octet-stream```

Comment: imports used???

Comment: For anyone that uses `io.BytesIO()` but doesn't set the original data at object creation, you must rewind the stream position back to the start of the file before calling `send_file`.

Answer (score 55):

Just wanted to confirm that dav1d's second suggestion is correct - I tested this (where obj.logo is a mongoengine ImageField), works fine for me:

```py
import io

from flask import current_app as app
from flask import send_file

from myproject import Obj

@app.route('/logo.png')
def logo():
    """Serves the logo image."""

    obj = Obj.objects.get(title='Logo')

    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(obj.logo.read()),
        download_name='logo.png',
        mimetype='image/png'
    )
```

Easier than manually creating a Response object and settings its headers.

<sub>Prior to Flask 2.0, `download_name` was called `attachment_filename`.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Suppose i have the stored image path with me. The below code helps to send image through.

```
from flask import send_file
@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    filename = 'uploads\\123.jpg'
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

uploads is my folder name where my image with 123.jpg is present.

[PS: The uploads folder should be in the current directory as of the your script file]

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if the image is in-memory.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me (for `Python 3.7.3`):

```
import io
import base64
# import flask
from PIL import Image

def get_encoded_img(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path, mode='r')
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
    my_encoded_img = base64.encodebytes(img_byte_arr.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
    return my_encoded_img

...
# your api code
...
img_path = 'assets/test.png'
img = get_encoded_img(img_path)
# prepare the response: data
response_data = {"key1": value1, "key2": value2, "image": img}
# return flask.jsonify(response_data )
```

Comment: Using this code on the server side, how I can I decode it in javascript? Encode the string as ascii then decode the bytes as base 64 and save it as an image?

Comment: Did you try: 
1. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/513 

2. https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/???

Comment: Hello, is there a way you could update to reflect showing the js part?

Comment: The conversion can be shown in the form of an example image that was read and converted to base64 format and then back to original. 
```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let buff = fs.readFileSync('images/inp.png');
let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
console.log(base64data)

let buffOut = new Buffer(base64data, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('images/out.png', buffOut);

console.log('Base64 image data converted to file: out.png');
```

Now you can figure out your part @boardkeystown

Comment: But this doesn't return raw binary, it returns base64 no?