# flask render opencv image on web without saving file

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

Basically I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask) to stream processed video (not just retrieving frames and broadcasting) and it works for me (I'm new to html and flask). But I want to save some computation here:

1. I wonder if it's possible to avoid saving opencv image object to a jpeg file and then reading again? Is it a waste of computation?
2. I think it's even better if flask/html template could render the image by using raw 3 data channels RGB of the image.

Any idea? Thanks!

P/S: I actually tried this following code:

```
_, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, [ int( cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY ), 95 ] )
```

But it gives the following error:

> Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/trungnb/virtual_envs/tf_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 704, in **next**
>       return self._next()
>     File "/home/trungnb/virtual_envs/tf_cpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 81, in _iter_encoded
>       for item in iterable:
>     File "/home/trungnb/workspace/coding/Mask_RCNN/web.py", line 25, in gen
>       if frame == None:
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What is on line 25 of web.py?

Comment: Right, it was correct in the first place! I was checking whether the frame that flask gets was None or not (in case the ip camera returns no frame sometimes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to compress it to JPEG anyway as sending the raw RGB data would be slower due to the data size.

You could try using cv::imencode to compress the image. Then you may be able send the image in a similar way to [flask return image created from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017466/flask-return-image-created-from-database)

Comment: So it was working without faking any headers. Thank you!