# Is there a way to turn PIL string bytes into a viewable image on my web application?

Tags: python, angular, python-imaging-library

I have marshalled PIL image into bytes  via `toBytes()` on my Flask Server.

Then these bytes was then embedded in Json as a string and transferred via http to my Angular web application.

Is there a way to turn this binary into a viewable image on my web application? Or is there a better way transfering image from my Flask server to my Angular web application?

Comment: How did you embed them? Base 64 or just throwing them in as UTF?

Comment: Also, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11017839/8997916

Comment: utf-8 bytes but I am sure I can add in base64 if needed

Comment: wouldnt it be possible to craft an image that encodes to a double quote to have a JSON injection? Seems unsecure

Comment: I think that link helps, I will  try that out later when I have the opportunity

Comment: Yes that is possible, I did that on another part of my system already; RaspberryPi -> Flask.

Comment: The link's suggestion may not work because I also want to send additional information in a form of JSON.

Comment: What is the security concern do you have?

Comment: right now you dump raw utf into a string. Now let's say an image has the byte 0x22. Thats " in utf. You are now outside of the string and can add arbitary json. (except if you escaped it, which now that im using my brain you probably have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of my code python flask code:

```
    imgByteArrTemp = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(imgByteArrTemp, format="PNG")
#        imgByteArrTemp = base64.b64encode(imgByteArrTemp.getvalue())
    imgByteArrTemp = imgByteArrTemp.getvalue()
```

My `GET` method:

```
@app.route("/get-resulting-image", methods=["GET"]) 
def get_resulting_image(): 
    global q 
    if not q.empty(): 
        item = q.get() 
        return send_file(io.BytesIO(item),
                mimetype = "image/png",
                as_attachment=True,
                download_name="%s.png")
    return "no image to provide"
```

My typescript app.component.ts:

```
createImageFromBlob(image:Blob){
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        this.imageBinary = reader.result;
        console.log(this.imageBinary);
    },false);
    if (image){
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
}   
getResponse(){
 ...
this.restService.getCorrespondingImage().subscribe( 
                            data1 => {
                                this.createImageFromBlob(data1);
                                this.isImageLoading = false;
                            },
                            error => {
                                this.isImageLoading = false;
                                console.log(error)
                            }
                        );
 ...
}
```

app.component.html

```
<img [src]="imageBinary" *ngIf="!isImageLoading">
```

rest.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, retry} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

....
    getCorrespondingImage():Observable<Blob>{
        return this.http.get(
            "http://192.168.1.2:9500/get-resulting-image",
            {responseType:"blob"});
    }   
}
```

Hope this could help someone out there.