# Why can't flask find this file?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to return a jpg file from a get request in Flask using this answer as a guide [How to return images in flask response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637153/how-to-return-images-in-flask-response)

I have this code running in my root directory (off a tornado server):

```
@app.route('/pic/<string:address>', methods= ["GET"])
def here(address=None):
    return send_file(url_for('static', filename='images/123_Octavia_St.jpg'), mimetype='image/jpg')
```

I have the file located at `rootdirectory/static/images/123_Octavia_St.jpg`

I am getting this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/images/123_Octavia_St.jpg'
```

Here are the paths:

```
$ pwd
pathto/rootdirectory/static/images
$ ls
123_Octavia_St.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `url_for()`; that's for generating URLs, not file paths.

Instead, use [`send_from_directory()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.send_from_directory) with the static directory as the root:

```
from flask import app, send_directory

@app.route('/pic/<string:address>', methods= ["GET"])
def here(address=None):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'images/123_Octavia_St.jpg', mimetype='image/jpg')
```

or, for static files, just reuse the view Flask uses for serving static files itself, [`app.send_static_file()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.send_static_file):

```
from flask import app

@app.route('/pic/<string:address>', methods= ["GET"])
def here(address=None):
    return app.send_static_file('images/123_Octavia_St.jpg')
```