# What is the difference between Flask's send_file and send_from_directory?

Tags: python, flask

It is still not clear for me when to use `send_file` and when `send_from_directory`.

I have a file in a folder protected. I can access the file from both methods. So perhaps someone has an example that makes clear which function should be used.

```
@app.route('/sfile/<id>')
def sfile(id=None):

    try:
        return send_file('protected/'+id, attachment_filename='python.jpg')
    except:
        return('')

@app.route('/sdir/<path:filename>')
def sdir(filename):
    try:
        return send_from_directory(
            os.path.join(app.instance_path, ''),
            filename
        )
    except:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 53):

`send_file` is the function that handles sending files to the user. It does no sanity check on the input, so it would also happily send `protected/../../../etc/passwd` or whatever. In your specific case that might not work, but if you are unaware of that type of attack you might produce unsecure code.

`send_from_directory` checks wether the requested file is really from the specified directory. That way the above attack would not work.

So you can use `send_file` whenenver the input filepath is trusted. That means either do your own checks or if the input is provided by you (e.g. `my_file_paths = {"a": "path/to/a", ... }; send_file(my_file_paths[user_input])` would be okay) you should be fine. For the common case `send_from_directory` is a helper function that does the appropriate security checks.