# Deploying a Machine Learning model as REST API using Flask. Error: RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: python, rest, api, machine-learning, flask

I've developed a classifier for test classification. and trying to access it using REST API. Here is the code:

```
clf_model = joblib.load('MNB_Clf.pkl','r')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/spend_api',methods=['POST'])
def make_predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)

    test_data = pd.read_csv(data)

    pred_proba_class = clf_model.predict_proba(test_data['ColumnName1'])


    final_pred_file = pd.DataFrame(pred_proba_class)

    sub_file = 'output_'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")) + '.csv'
    return jsonify(results=final_pred_file.to_csv(sub_file))
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port = 9000,debug=True)
```

I am trying to send the CSV file to the api using the below code:

```
url = 'http://localhost:9000/spend_api'
files = {'file': ('Test_data_final.csv')}
r = request.post(url,files=files)
```

I am getting a Runtime Error. Could you please help how to resolve the issue.

Here is the error:

```
  RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call 
  last)
  <ipython-input-15-4b8522aa1eb0> in <module>()
         3 url = 'http://localhost:9000/spend_api'
         4 files = {'file': ('Test_data_final.csv')}
   ----> 5 r = request.post(url,files=files)
         6 
         7 

      C:\Users\pavansubhash_t\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site -
    packages\werkzeug\local.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
         345         if name == '__members__':
    346             return dir(self._get_current_object())
--> 347         return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
    348 
    349     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

C:\Users\pavansubhash_t\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.pyc in _get_current_object(self)
    304         """
    305         if not hasattr(self.__local, '__release_local__'):
--> 306             return self.__local()
    307         try:
    308             return getattr(self.__local, self.__name__)

C:\Users\pavansubhash_t\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.pyc in _lookup_req_object(name)
     35     top = _request_ctx_stack.top
     36     if top is None:
---> 37         raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
     38     return getattr(top, name)
     39 

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Comment: Please post  complete error output. Also try to reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Christoph Edited the code as suggested. Please suggest how can I resolve the issue

Comment: @pavansubhash please share a minum reproducible example. I think you lost the identation when you pasted to SO. If not, start fixing that, The definition of the post request handler function make_predict is not clear.

Comment: @MedAli Is it fine now ? My apologies for the inappropriate identation

Comment: If you could add print after each step, it might help understanding the problem. Otherwise, there is a problem in this line:     `return jsonify(results=final_pred_file.to_csv(sub_file))`. You can't jsonfiy a CSV file. The to_csv operation is going to send None, its role is to write to a file in the disk where you are executing your code. If you want to send a JSON, you should use final_pred_file.to_dict(orient="records")

Comment: Also, there is a mistake in your use of request to upload the file. Check the answer in this question for the correct way to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What should I do to return my output from the model as a .csv file?

Comment: you should use send_file. It can be import as follows `from flask import send_file`. Here's an example on how to send an image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637153/how-to-return-images-in-flask-response . Customize it to fit your need.

Comment: @MedAli I tried everything that has been mentioned in above comments. I am getting a connection error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your requirement, you have a pre-trained classifier and you want to serve classification over an API. Your API receives a CSV file as input and sends back another CSV file. To refactor your code to do that, you need to add the follow changes.

## Fix how you are sending the file in a request:

Fix the way you are loading the csv file into the files dictionary as follows:

```
url = 'http://localhost:9000/spend_api'
files = {'file': open('Test_data_final.csv','rb')}
r = request.post(url,files=files)
```

you can find more details in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload) thread.

## Fix how to send the json response

```
clf_model = joblib.load('MNB_Clf.pkl','r')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/spend_api',methods=['POST'])
def make_predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)

    test_data = pd.read_csv(data)
    pred_proba_class = clf_model.predict_proba(test_data['ColumnName1'])
    final_pred_file = pd.DataFrame(pred_proba_class)
    return jsonify(results=final_pred_file.to_dict(orient="records"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port = 9000,debug=True)
```

## If you want to send a CSV file instead

here is a standalone working example:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import send_file 
from StringIO import StringIO 
import pandas as pd 

app = Flask("csv")

@app.route("/get_csv")
def hello():

    st = """col1|col2
    1|2
    3|4 
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), sep="|")
    df.to_csv("/tmp/my_test_csv.csv", index=False, sep="|")
    return send_file("/tmp/my_test_csv.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

As a side note, I suggest that you rethink your design to use JSON instead.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, now I am getting a ConnectionError:   ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))

Comment: @pavansubhash your example doesn't reproduce the error. Unless you share a minimum example that I can run on my machine and exactly your error, I can't help you much. In the answer, I tried to give enough information in order to help fix the visible issue. Now, it's up to you.