# Relative path in Flask is not picking up a file

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building my first Flask application on local machine and have issues with path to images that I use in my HTML.

My folder structure is very simple:

```
-templates folder
     -assets folder
         - cover.jpeg
         - index.html
```

In my index.html I use relative path `assets/cover.jpeg` which should show a picture in my homepage. When I refresh homepage, it shows image placeholder only. When I open this pic in a new tab, it opens URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/assets/cover.jpeg`

and displays:

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I then tried full path to core folder of my project `/templates/assets/cover.jpeg` and got same thing, pointing now at

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/templates/assets/cover.jpeg`

It is probably something really silly, but I cannot make my picture displayed.

Comment: If your homepage is index.html, then you can just provide the path as "assets.jpeg" which should suffice.

Comment: If I use only 'cover.jpeg' (I believe this is what you meant), the picture's url is 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/cover.jpeg' and it does not show picture as well

Comment: Okay, you want to return an image from a flask app. This is possible by using send_file in flask.

Comment: READ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637153/how-to-return-images-in-flask-response

Comment: Solution was found. It was reeeaaally silly, but I am a beginner and this is what they do, right? =)) I created 'static' folder and used path like 'static/assets/cover.jpg'