# How to display images from folder in Python html and flask

Tags: python

I am very new to python and Flask.
I have a folder with a list of jpeg images. I have to display them in my demo application with flask as below,
My app.py :

```
@app.route("/")
def home():  
    return render_template('home.html')
```

My home.html:

```html
<img id="person" src={{ url_for('static',filename='pferson_folder/000_1.jpg') }}>
```

In the above code, I don't want to hardcode the images in the HTML tag. it needs to take the image source from folder dynamically.

Would you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637153/how-to-return-images-in-flask-response

Answer (score 4):

You can read all the file names out of the directory using `os.listdir('Your path')` and pass the array into the template:

Something like:

```py
# Inside app.py
import os
@app.route('/')
def home():
 image_names = os.listdir('Your path to images folder')
 render_template('home.html', image_name=image_names)
```

And inside your template:

```html
{% for name in image_names %}
 <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pferson_folder/' + name) }}" >
{% endfor %}
```

Then you don't have to hardcode the names.