# Flask + Leaflet - How to use custom local tiles ? (GET 404 Not Found)

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, leaflet

I am trying to create a Leaflet map with custom tiles on top of OSM base layer (from Leaflet.js), using Flask. 
I generated a set of tiles from geo-referenced GeoTIFF images, and I first visualized them using standard CSS / HTML / JS to quickly check the result,

```js
// maps.js
L.tileLayer('data/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {tms: true, opacity: 0.7, attribution: ""});
```

and everything was working.

[image: custom tiles displayed with only HTML / CSS / JS]

However, when I switched to flask, I got a `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/tiles/7/61/83.png 404 (NOT FOUND)` error.

[image: custom tiles are not rendering with Flask]

I am new to Flask, and I suspect that the error comes from a routing connection.

**What I tried**

I tried to add a new route from my `app.py` file, so Flask could find the images:

```py
# app.py
@app.route('/data/tiles/<path:img>', methods=['GET'])
def tile(img):
    return f'data/tiles/{img}'
```

This solved the errors `GET [...] 404 (NOT FOUND)` problem, but the tiles were still not loaded / displayed.

### Project structure:

/ my_app / 
| - -   app.py 
| 
| - -   templates 
|       | - -   maps.html 
| 
| - -   static 
|       | - -   css 
|       |       | - -   maps.css 
|       | 
|       | - -   js 
|       |       | - -   maps.js 
| 
| - -   data 
|       | - -   tiles 
|       |       | - - sub-folders containing pyramid images, 
|       |       |     in 'z/x/y.png' format

### The code:

*app.py*

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/maps")
def maps():
    return render_template('maps.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*maps.html*

```html
<!-- Basic import (Leaflet) -->
<!-- ... and layout style -->

<script type='text/javascript' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/maps.js') }}"></script>
```

*maps.js*

```js
// Base layers
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'});

// Overlay layer
var lyr = L.tileLayer('data/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {tms: true, opacity: 0.7, attribution: ""});

// Map
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [47.81260945134799, -6.375234248965416],
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 10,
    layers: [osm]
});

var basemaps = {"OpenStreetMap": osm}
var overlaymaps = {"Layer": lyr}

// Add base layers
L.control.layers(basemaps, overlaymaps, {collapsed: true}).addTo(map);
```

Thanks !

## Edit:

I finally got it working thanks to @IvanSanchez comment.

From the post, I added a new route in `app.py`:

```py
# app.py
@app.route('/data/tiles/<path:img>')
def get_image(img):
    filename = f'data/tiles/{img}'
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/png')
```

This added my custom tiles to my Leaflet map.
However, I got another error because my tiles didn't covered fully the world. 
I fixed it by adding a bounding box to my Leaflet layer:

```js
// maps.js

// Overlay layer
var lyr = L.tileLayer('data/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {bounds: [[50, -16.24],[43, -0.2]], tms: true, opacity: 0.7, attribution: ""});
```

Thanks again for all your help !

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637153/how-to-return-images-in-flask-response ?

Comment: Thank you ! It is finally working.